# Why use lambda layers instead of just plain code?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For example:

```
inp = keras.Input(shape=s)
D = keras.layers.Dense(d)(inp)
L = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: myFunc(x))(D)
outp = keras.layers.Dense(...)(L)
model = keras.model(inp,outp)
```

vs.

```
inp = keras.Input(shape=s)
D = keras.layers.Dense(d)(inp)
L = myFunc(D)
outp = keras.layers.Dense(...)(L)
model = keras.model(inp,outp)
```

where `myFunc` is made up of tensorflow functions.

The latter version seems to work just fine. Is there any special value in wrapping stuff as layers?  I understand it might be required when there are learnable parameters, but I would use a custom layer in such a case, not a lambda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think functionally there are too many incentives for using `tf.keras.layers.Lambda`. But there's a few I can think of.

#### Readability

I like to use them mainly for consistency and descript-ability. I find it a but messy when layers used with raw TF operations altogether.

For example, I can easily do,

`tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: do_cool(x), name="cool_thing")`

which will reflect in the `model.summary()`

### Masking

With `Lambda` layer you can pass in the `mask` parameter to handle masking, whereas with TF ops, your code will become easily messy for masking.

### Important notes

- It's not advisable to use `Lambda` layer for operations involving `tf.Variable` objects. They won't be passed as trainable variables in your model.
- `Lambda` ops are stateless. So for any stateful operations, `Lambda` is a no go.
- I'm not 100% sure about this one, but I assume TF does some implicit wrapping of TF operations as Lambda layers anyway when you use them in a model (going with the `TFOpLambda` I see when printing `model.summary()`).